# iPhone: How to Get an Entry for an App in the Settings?

Tags: iphone, settings, appsettings

I am doing a movieplayer application and I  want to activate certain settings about my application in settings.

What are the steps should I do to get an entry for my app in the settings of iphone/itouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a decent tutorial for creating a Settings Bundle for your app:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file